# simple form shows ActiveRecord Relation when using using a non all query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

The issue:

[image: User Dropdown shows a ActiveRecord Relation]

I would like the drop down to list the last name of the user. How can accomplish this?

`app/controllers/courses_controller`

```
  def edit
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @teachers = User.where('teacher is true').order(:last_name).all
  end
```

View

```
= simple_form_for @course do |f|
  - if @course.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@course.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this course from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @course.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.input :name
  .field
    = f.input :password
  .field
    = f.input :description
  - if @current_user
    - if @current_user.admin?
      = f.input :user, collection: @teachers
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections):

> Collection inputs accept two other options beside collections:
>
> > • label_method => the label method to be applied to the collection to retrieve the label (use this instead of the text_method option in collection_select)
> >
> > • value_method => the value method to be applied to the collection to retrieve the value

```
= f.input :user, collection: @teachers, label_method: :last_name
```